# Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header from the Dropbox API

Tags: php, dropbox-api

When I try a simple curl request to the Dropbox API (v2), I get this error:

```
Error in call to API function "users/get_current_account": Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Expecting one of "application/json", "application/json; charset=utf-8", "text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack".
```

The PHP code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken) );
echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `CURLOPT_POST` option specifies a content type (to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, based on [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)). It's possible instead to make it a POST request using the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` option.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken) );
echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```